# urlencode except /

Tags: php, urlencode

Is there a way to urlencode except directory seperators / in the path ?

like

```
urlencode('/this/is/my/file right here.jpg');
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use

- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to split your path into the path segments,
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to apply [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) on each item (don’t use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode), that’s only for [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded* encoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) query arguments!), and
- [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to put the segments back together.

So all together in one line:

```
$path = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $path)));
```

Comment: This would be the most conceptually correct way of doing it, though in practice the `str_replace` would be simpler. Either way +1 for `rawurlencode`; it is always the right thing, whereas `urlencode` is sometimes the wrong thing.

Answer (score 16):

Replace them again:

```
str_replace('%2F', '/', urlencode('/this/is/my/file right here.jpg'));
```

Note that if you are going to pass the result in a query string, you should not do the replacement above -- use only `urlencode`. If you are using it in the path portion, you ought to use [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/rawurlencode) instead.

Comment: This one sounds nice too. It must be much faster than the selected answer I guess.

Comment: This covers 99% of cases. The 1% are the paths in which 2%F is not intended to be converted but an actual part of the path string.

Comment: @Tyblitz 2%F would be encoded to 2%25F if it were part of the path string.

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem.

```
str_replace("%2F","/",urlencode('/this/is/my/file right here.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = explode('/', '/this/is/my/file right here.jpg');
foreach ($array as &$value) {
        $value = urlencode($value);
}
print implode('/', $array);
```